# Why is my ASP.NET Core middleware pipeline short-circuit code returning an empty response?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an ASP.NET Core web application in which I have a pipeline of several custom middleware functions. I'm trying to add a new one to the beginning of the pipeline that [short-circuits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-webapplication) the rest of my custom middleware if condition is met. You can see here in my code that the "allow anonymous" middleware has been inserted at the beginning of my middleware functions.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseMiddleware<AllowAnonymousMiddleware>()
        .UseMiddleware<ClientAuthorizedMiddleware>()
        .UseMiddleware<CatalogUserMiddleware>()
        .UseMiddleware<PolicyAllowedMiddleware>();

    app.UseEndpoints(ConfigureEndpoints);
}
```

This `AllowAnonymousMiddleware` looks like the following ...

```
public class AllowAnonymousMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AllowAnonymousMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
        var allowsAnonymous = endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>();

        if (allowsAnonymous == null)
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

It has some code in it that will either call the next pipeline method or return, skipping the remainder of the pipeline.

My problem is that when it returns, without calling the remainder of the pipeline, I just get an empty response.

Shouldn't it proceed to the endpoint routing and return the result of my endpoint action methods?

How can I make it so that the allow anonymous middleware function only skips the 3 middleware functions that I have chained after it?

Comment: The endpoint routing is at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: If it's before my middleware, won't the routing always happen before middleware? Making the middleware never execute?

Edit: OK, just tried shuffling those around. I did not realize it worked that way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving my conditional logic out of a middleware and into a `UseWhen` call. This works because I wanted to only apply middleware in a certain situation. Below is the code that I used to address my issues ...

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

using WhatInBoxWorkspaceApi.Middleware;

namespace WhatInBoxWorkspaceApi.Common
{
    public static class WorkspaceAuthorizationMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseWorkspaceAuthorization(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseWhen(EndpointRequiresAuthentication, ApplyMiddleware);
        }

        private static bool EndpointRequiresAuthentication(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
            var allowsAnonymous = endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>();

            return allowsAnonymous == null;
        }

        private static void ApplyMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
                .UseMiddleware<ClientAuthorizedMiddleware>()
                .UseMiddleware<CatalogUserMiddleware>()
                .UseMiddleware<PolicyAllowedMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```